# How to pass an interface using intent

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, parcelable, serializable

This is my Interface class

```
interface InstallerInterface {
     fun onInstallation(context: Context)
}
```

I implements the interface in this class

```
class FirstActivity : InstallerInterface{
    override fun onInstallation(context: Context) {
         *MyCode*
    }
}
```

I have tried to pass this context using intent to

```
 val intent=Intent(context,SecondActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("NAME",name)
        intent.putExtra("Callback",Interface)
        context.startActivity(intent)
```

But intent.putExtra was causing error `Cannot resolve method 'putExtra()` . So I implements `Serializable` in `FirstActivity()` class. But that was causing error

```
06-11 12:28:57.323  4042  4042 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = FirstAcitvity)
06-11 12:28:57.323  4042  4042 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1535)
06-11 12:28:57.323  4042  4042 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1483)
06-11 12:28:57.323  4042  4042 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:732)
06-11 12:28:57.323  4042  4042 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1417)
06-11 12:28:57.323  4042  4042 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1157)
06-11 12:28:57.323  4042  4042 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:772)
06-11 12:28:57.323  4042  4042 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:8703)
06-11 12:28:57.323  4042  4042 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:3082)
06-11 12:28:57.323  4042  4042 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1520)
06-11 12:28:57.323  4042  4042 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4229)
06-11 12:28:57.323  4042  4042 E AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
06-11 12:28:57.323  4042  4042 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4187)
06-11 12:28:57.323  4042  4042 E AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
06-11 12:28:57.323  4042  4042 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4526)
06-11 12:28:57.323  4042  4042 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4494)
06-11 12:28:57.323  4042  4042 E AndroidRuntime:        at foundation.e.apps.XAPK.LaunchUtils.startInstallSplitApksActivity(LaunchUtils.kt:15)
06-11 12:28:57.323  4042  4042 E AndroidRuntime:        at foundation.e.apps.XAPK.ViewUtils$installXApk$1.onCompedApks(ViewUtils.kt:57)
06-11 12:28:57.323  4042  4042 E AndroidRuntime:        at foundation.e.apps.XAPK.XApkInstallUtils$installSplitApks$2.run(XApkInstallUtils.kt:191)
06-11 12:28:57.323  4042  4042 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
06-11 12:28:57.323  4042  4042 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-11 12:28:57.323  4042  4042 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
06-11 12:28:57.323  4042  4042 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186)
06-11 12:28:57.323  4042  4042 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-11 12:28:57.323  4042  4042 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
06-11 12:28:57.323  4042  4042 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-11 12:28:57.323  4042  4042 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: ThirdAcivity()
06-11 12:28:57.323  4042  4042 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1224)
06-11 12:28:57.323  4042  4042 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1584)
06-11 12:28:57.323  4042  4042 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1549)
06-11 12:28:57.323  4042  4042 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1472)
06-11 12:28:57.323  4042  4042 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1218)
06-11 12:28:57.323  4042  4042 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
06-11 12:28:57.323  4042  4042 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1530)
06-11 12:28:57.323  4042
```

I believe `ThirdActivity()` implements the `FirstActivity()` and I was not implementing `Serializable` in `ThirdAcivity`. So I implement `Serializable` in `ThirdAcitivity` . And I was getting error on every Activity which uses `FirstAcivity`. This is a large project and I can't implement `Serializable` on every Acitivity.
So I implement `Parcelable` instead. My code is

```
@Parcelize
class FirstActivity : InstallerInterface, Parcelable{
    override fun onInstallation(context: Context) {
         *MyCode*
    }
}
```

And I was getting error like `java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value`
How can I fix this code. If not, What could be better alternative. Thank you in advance

Comment: Why you want pass an Interface to another class? Can you please add more details?

Comment: I think you want to listen to an event using the interface implemented in FirstActivity from SecondActivity? If that is the case try using startActivityForResult method.  You can chain this to get results even from 3rd activity to 1st activity https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

Comment: If you want to use context in non-activity class then you can try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17917968/get-context-in-non-activity-class

Comment: I want to call  the interface function`onInstallation()` of `FirstActivity()` from `SecondActivity` . Like `callback.onInstallation`. I was not able to pass the interface using  `intent.putExtra` to `SecondActivity`. The main idea is to get the context of the interface class

Comment: https://gitlab.e.foundation/DayonaJ/apps/-/commit/685cbb5952e7374b7925f0ff8712f4bdf1c60606. Here is what Iam doing. I want to call `onInstalationComplete()` of class `Application.kt` (which is `InstallerInterface.kt`  method) from `InstallSplitApksActivity.kt`

Answer (score 0):

Yours' activities should't implement `Parcelable/Serializable`. Also passing activity references may cause memory leaks and app crushes (https://proandroiddev.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-memory-leaks-in-android-d7a59faaf46a, https://techbeacon.com/app-dev-testing/what-you-need-know-about-android-app-memory-leaks)

If you want to do something in another activity and return result to the first activity you could use `startActivityForResult` or new `Activity Result APIs`. More information https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

Comment: I don't want return result from activity. I just want to know when activity ends. I have tried `startActivityForResult` . But `onActivityResult` is not called.

Comment: Here is my code.
```
fun startInstallSplitApksActivity(context: Activity, apksBean: ApksBean,  callback:InstallerInterface) { 

val intent =installSplitApksActivity.newInstanceIntent(context, apksBean, callback)
        context.startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
 
}

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode==1) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                myCode()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `I just want to know when activity ends` - I think event that activity ends is some kind of result. Yours code with `startActivityForResult` looks good, but don't you forget to call `setResult()` at InstallActivity before calling `finish()`?

Comment: Yes, added `setResult()`.But override `nextStep()` is  from another class-BaseActivity().Is that the issue?
`override fun nextStep() {
        super.nextStep()
        apksBean = intent.getParcelableExtra(KEY_PARAM)
        if (apksBean == null || apksBean!!.splitApkPaths.isNullOrEmpty()){
                val  intent = Intent()
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK)
                finish() }`

`abstract class BaseActivity : RxAppCompatActivity() {
      override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        nextStep()
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "pass an interface". An "interface" is an abstract thing. What you want to pass is a concrete implementation of that interface, ie: an object (that happens to implement your interface). When you instantiate your "interface" (in your example, like this:

```
intent.putExtra("testInterface", new ITest() {
    @Override 
    void onSuccess(String text) {
    }
}
```

However, even if you did that, it would not solve your problem. What you need to understand is that you can't pass objects (instances) by putting them as "extras" in an Intent. When you do that, Android actually serializes and then deserializes the object so that you end up with 2 objects, one is a serialized/deserialized copy of the original.

[For more Details:->](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38894352/12376616)