# Pass an interface between activities in intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, interface

I have this situation: a Class A (that implements interface I), a Modal and a Class B (that implements interface I).

The Class A open the modal, and from the modal I go to class B. In class B I want to return to the Class A with the Modal updated (Not implemented yet).

I'm trying to pass an interface between the two activities but I recive this error (I already extends Serializable in Interface):

```
 Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
```

Class A

```
@Override
public void showList() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SelectMethod.class);
            intent.putExtra("iHome", this);
            startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Modal

```
 # Function when click button and go to the class B
 btn_select_method.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            iHome.showList();
        }
    });
```

Class B (SelectMethod)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     intent.getSerializableExtra("iHome");
}
```

Interface

```
public interface Ihome extends Serializable {
    void showList();
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38894352/9701793, have a look into it.

Answer (score 1):

To a class be serializable all of this fields need to be serializable (can write/read keeping state), any class that extends View have fields that are not serializable like Contexts and Listeners, those are instances.

You should not try to pass the activity/views/fragments instances trough intents since it breaks android lifecycle behaviour.

Since you using a Activity with modal theme, you may use

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 25 /*any number */)
```

Then into SelectMethod instead of calling a method from the FirstActivity you `setResult` then `finish`

The result is read from FirstActivity into:

```
@Override public void onActivityResult
```

See more: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#kotlin

Comment: I have the issue that you comments, my first class extends View. On the other hand  the startActivityForResult was deprecated in java and I dont understand how can use the ActivityResultLauncher (new function) in this situation.

Comment: Try with the deprecated API its just recently deprecated, after that you can move to the new